# Oracle 11G - it's possible write Table valued function?

Tags: oracle, plsql, resultset

In **SQL SERVER** I wrote some **Table-Valued Functions** to execute parameterized queries to the database and the returned results sets were used in the creation of reports, now in **ORACLE 11** I need to do the same, however, Oracle does not have Table-Valued Functions and what I have at my disposal Procedures, View and functions.

Researching on the INTERNET I found that to do the work it is necessary to use Cursors, is this the only way to do the work? Is there a simpler and more efficient way to do it?

Here is the sample code tested in Oracle:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_EST_PRUEBAS(P_ODS IN NUMBER, LISTADO OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN
  OPEN LISTADO FOR
        SELECT 
            field1,
            COUNT(field1) AS count_field1
        FROM table1 A
            INNER JOIN table2 b ON b.idtable = A.idtable
        WHERE A.idods = P_ODS
        GROUP BY field1;
END SP_EST_PRUEBAS;
/

-- testing in Oracle SQL Developer
VARIABLE mycursor refcursor;
EXEC SP_EST_PRUEBAS (3836, :mycursor);
PRINT mycursor
/
```

I appreciate any suggestions in this regard.

Comment: What type object can give me best performance?

Comment: Everything depends on the program that is calling it and what it is expecting in return.  Just take of your MSSQL goggles.  Best practice in one rdbms is often worst practice in another - and that works both directions. Unless your data volumes are truly massive, performance shouldn't be an issue - certainly not in choosing between procedure vs. function, as they are both just bits of code written in PL/SQL.  Oracle11g is way, way out of date and, unless you are paying through the nose, effectively out of support.

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review [ask]. Following that as a template greatly enhances your change of getting a satisfactory answer. In particular you need table descriptions (DDL), example data - as [formatted text](https://senseful.github.io/text-table/)-**no images** and the expected output from that data. Might also be useful to describe Table-Valued Functions for those of us that do not use SQL server.

Comment: You should get rid of the final [slash](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/slash.html), as it runs the last SQL statement or PL/SQL block, not SQL\*Plus commands like `print` or `exec`.